# Converting NSString to NSData and vice versa

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata, data-conversion

I am having an issue while trying to convert `NSString` to `NSData` and vice versa.
I am trying to store encrypted string to my database. For that I am using AES algorithm. Now what I am doing is I get encrypted `NSData` and I am converting this to `NSString` using following:

```
// Not woking
NSString *strTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

// Working
NSString *strTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Why `NSData` is not converting while using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Same way when I try to convert the string got by `NSASCIIStringEncoding` using:

```
// Not working
[strTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Working
[strTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Why `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is not working while converting the `NSString` to `NSData`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`NSString` to `NSData`:

```
NSString* str= @"teststring";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`NSData` to `NSString`:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is what I am doing in my first code spinit.. but getting a nil string

Comment: the code is total here... I have a string I m converting it in Data using `[strTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` working but `[strTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]` not working similarly the data I got using `[strTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` I am converting back to string using `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:encData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]` is working but `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:encData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` is not. So Every time my conversion occurs I am using different encoding that have no surety of same result.

Comment: NSString* str= @"teststring";
    NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
     
    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
    
     
    NSString* str1= @"teststring";
    NSData* data1=[str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     
    NSLog(@"%@",data1);
     
    NSString* newStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",newStr1);

I have tested it and its working fine !!! in both cases

Answer (score 2):

Please mind that `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and `NSUTF8StringEncoding` need to match the characters in the string.