# How to scan and replace content in text files

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, replace

I need to write a Mac project that can localize the annotation of the method and property in .h file.

I can use the code

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setMessage:@"Import one or more files or directories."];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NSHomeDirectory()]];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"h", nil]];

[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        NSArray *urls = [panel URLs];
        NSLog(@"urls : %@",[urls description]);
    }
}];
```

to get the URLs of the files.

But I can't find a way to scan all the .h file and get the content of the .h files,let alone exchange the annotation. I really appreciate your help,thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this from the command line?  Using the UI makes no sense.

Comment: NSOpenPanel is fine to get URLs of your files. Then to open, read and write to the files, you'll need some other classes.

Answer (score 0):

To read, scan and write to text-files, it's easiest to use `NSMutableData` and `dataWithContentsOfURL`:

Then parse with NSString and the like, see
[Converting NSString to NSData and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745720/converting-nsstring-to-nsdata-and-vice-versa)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I write the codes like this:

//1、scan all the .h file.

```
-(NSArray *)filesWithSuffix:(NSString *)suffix atFilePath:(NSString *)path{
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError * error;
NSArray * array = [fileManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *ele in array){

    if ([[ele substringFromIndex:(ele.length - suffix.length)] isEqualToString:suffix]){
        [mutableArray addObject:ele];
    }
}
return [mutableArray copy];}
```

and call the method:

```
NSArray *filePaths = [self filesWithSuffix:@".h" atFilePath:path];
```